# Best way to handle multiple photos in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip.

I have multiple models that have photos. Products, Users, Links - all can have multiple photos each.

So I want to have 1 photo model. What is the relationship I need to have here?

I'd rather not have user_photos, link_photos, product_photos, etc. Or is the the only method?

Is it possible to just have 1 photo model?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/45-use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads

Answer (score 1):

I would use a polymorphic association.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photographable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :photographable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :photographable
end
```

For a polymorphic association, your `photos` table will need two columns, `photographable_type` and `photographable_id`.